# How to flatten a list of lists and join with a separator

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

How to join list of lists with separator?

For example:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

with separator:

```
0
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Why the separator is used at the ending in the first and at the last in the last?

Comment: 'separator'.join([str(x) for x in [list]). what u expecte result? string or list

Comment: @thefourtheye: It's pretty much the same behavior as `str.join`.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, it makes sense now... I complicated it with `zip` and stuff... Sigh

Comment: @simar I need list as result.

Comment: Looking at these answers really makes me glad we have `str.join`. I think every answer was wrong or quadratic-time (i.e. subtly wrong) in its original posted state.

Answer (score 11):

For example your list is stored in `x`:

```
x=[[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7]]
```

Simply use `reduce` with lambda function:

```
y=reduce(lambda a,b:a+[0]+b,x)
```

Now `y` is

```
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7]
```

Or you could define an generator function:

```
def chainwithseperator(lis,sep):
  it=iter(lis)
  for item in it.next():
    yield item
  for sublis in it:
    yield sep
    for item in sublis:
      yield item
```

Now calling:

```
y=list(chainwithseperator(x,0))
```

Will bring you the same result

Comment: This runs in quadratic time, since `+` for lists runs in time linear in the sum of the sizes of the arguments.

Comment: I'm not convinced when run with `x = [[1, 2]]` that `[1, 2, 0]` is the correct result... same with `x =[[1,2], [3,4,5]]`

Comment: @JonClements you are right i solved the problem in the generator but it makes it an little more complicated

Comment: @Lee +1 for the `reduce` - that's what I'd go for (it might just be worth noting in your answer that if OP is using Python 3.x, then they'll need a `from functools import reduce`)... I've also proposed a generator solution which I think is a bit cleaner using some `itertools` stuff, but `reduce` is easily the best way here :)

Answer (score 2):

That's how I would do it:

```
l = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7]]
result = [number for sublist in l for number in sublist+[0]][:-1]
```

The last `[:-1]` is to remove the last item which is a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `tee` the `list` as an iterable and only yield the separator when there's a following item. Here we're defining a function called `joinlist` which contains a generator helper function to yield the appropriate elements, then returns a flattened list of all those elements using `chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import tee, chain

def joinlist(iterable, sep):
    def _yielder(iterable):
        fst, snd = tee(iterable)
        next(snd, [])
        while True:
            yield next(fst)
            if next(snd, None):
                yield [sep]
    return list(chain.from_iterable(_yielder(iterable)))
```

It's important to note that the termination for the `while True:` occurs in `yield next(fst)` as that'll raise a `StopIteration` at some point and will cause the generator to exit.

**Example**:

```
x = [[1,2]]
y = [[1, 2], [3,4,5]]
z = [[1, 2], [3,4,5], [6, 7]]

for item in (x, y, z):
    print item, '->', joinlist(item, 0)

# [[1, 2]] -> [1, 2]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]] -> [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]] -> [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with Python list [extend()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method:

```
orig_list = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7]]
out_list = []
for i in orig_list:
    out_list.extend(i + [0])

# To remove the last element '0'.  
print my_list[:-1]
```